# Control flash message

Tags: python, flask, flash-message

I have some python code to show a flash message only if my query has no results, but I am getting this message (no results) before my query, when I click on my webpage. Is there a way to show the message only after my query? I tried to put the flash code in the html page in different locations, but I do not think this is the issue.
My python code is:

```
geneid=request.args.get('geneid')
sql=text('select * from INFO where name=:ident')
gene=engine.execute(sql,ident=geneid).fetchone()
params['obj']=gene
if gene is None:
    flash('NO RESULTS')
return render_template('info.html', **params)
```

Excerpt from my info.html:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
{% for message in messages: %}
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3 alert alert-success text-center"><strong><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>{{message}}</strong></div></div>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It must be the value of `gene` is None. The condition in if statement is values true. Try to print `gene` before `if`.

Comment: It did not work.